# How do you show/hide delete(remove) product button in the Cart?

Tags: commerce

I have an issue with the delete/remove product button from the Shopping Cart. Some of my products show and some don't (see screenshot below). I checked the rules and can't find this anywhere.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to have the <kbd>Remove</kbd> on another collection I created. It only works for Postpaid Collection which is the BLU Studio X product. However, the <kbd>Remove</kbd> link doesn't appear on the top product (above the red arrow where I want the <kbd>Remove</kbd> to show on that product as well).

There is a rule set somewhere and I can't find it. I even created a new product variation and content, and it doesn't show the link in the shopping cart. It only shows it for the Phone product that was created by the previous user.

Answer (score 1):

Shopping cart in Drupal commerce is a view. To remove the "remove" link, all you need to do is edit it and remove the "remove" field.

The view can be found at `/admin/structure/views/view/commerce_cart_form/edit`
and remove the field `(Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line Item: Delete button (Remove)`

Comment: I know about this setting, but I don't want to disable the remove from everything. I want to enable it for a specific product collection and this does not achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this bit out, I fixed this by checking the custom modules the previous developer added, and found that I had to add the line item type of the product, in the php code.